# Agrupar duas tabelas

Tags: postgresql

Possuo duas tabelas. Uma chamada `Pessoa` e outra chamada `Evento`.

`Pessoa` possui os campos `id`, `name` e `email`.
`Evento` possui os campos `id` e `pessoa_id`.

A tabela `Evento` contém vários eventos para cada `Pessoa`.

Gostaria de agrupar todas as pessoas, e a quantidade de eventos relacionados a ela. A nova tabela seria:

```
| Pessoa | Email           | Quantidade Eventos |
| nome1  | nome1@email.com | 5                  |
| nome2  | nome2@email.com | 10                 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma opção é usar um *subselect*:

```
SELECT p.nome, p.email,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eventos e
        WHERE e.pessoa_id = p.pessoa_id) AS qtde_eventos
FROM pessoas p
ORDER BY p.nome
```

Answer (score 1):

A subconsulta correlacionada é executada uma vez para cada linha do resultado o que pode ter um desempenho muito ruim. Ao invés faça a junção das tabelas:

```
select p.name, p.email, count(*) as eventos
from
    pessoa p
    left join
    evento e on p.id = e.pessoa_id
group by p.id, p.name, p.email
order by p.name
;
 name  |      email      | eventos 
-------+-----------------+---------
 nome1 | nome1@email.com |       5
 nome2 | nome2@email.com |      10
```